# How to know if running inside temporal workflow when using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, temporal-workflow

How can I know if I'm running inside temporal workflow when using the TypeScript SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import { inWorkflowContext } from '@temporalio/workflow';

if(inWorkflowContext()) {
   // ...
}
```